# Why AutoKey soft faster than bare Python script?

Tags: python, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, autokey

I just have moved to **Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS** from **Windows**, where I was active user of the **AutoHotKey**.

So, I have created **.py** script file with the following code:

[image]

This script is to move between Google Chrome browser tabs. Just for script test reasons.

So, when I tap keys - script is working, **but I feel noticeable delay. About 0.5 second. It is not suitable for me.**

Then, I have created same setup for AutoKey:

[image]

It works perfect. Superfast, instant, like AutoHotKey in Windows.

But actually I don't want to have this type "gasket" with AutoKey. I am good in Python, and it will be better for my to use simple Python without any additional software.

So, my question: **Why AutoKey much faster than bare Python script?
Are there any ways to boost my bare Python script?**

Comment: Python is an interpreted language - every time you run it, it has to load python and parse the entire script, including imports before it executes.  This is a massive overhead.  Try creating an executable using pyinstaller.

Comment: @cup I tried pyinstaller, but I am not sure that it helped. Maybe it helps to the script to be a bit faster, but I still feel delay. Anyway, thank you for your comment! :)